# HTML5 Video - fading out a video at the end without knowing the video length

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Is it possible to fade-out an html5 video right before it comes to an end?

Lets say we build a fade-out function which lasts 0.3 seconds. What we would then need to achieve is trigger the function exaclty 0.3 seconds before the end of the video. The problem is that I will not be able to know the exact length of the video, so how will javascript (or jQuery) know when to trigger the function?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: Hey @str, I know the list of media events but I dont see how any of them can help me. For example, "ended" triggers when the video has ended but I need to trigger a function shortly before the end. Can you point me to the specific media event which would help me do that?

Comment: `durationchange` and `timeupdate` should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Unfortunately, I have no idea how to achieve the fade-out with them. Could perhaps post an answer with some example code so I can mark this question as resolved?

Comment: Why don't you know their duration, or when it will end (if not the same)?

Comment: @Kaiido Because the source of the video is changed via javascript. Here is a fiddle I am working on: http://jsfiddle.net/9pv128tm/1/ You can see that I am already fading-in the videos but I don't know how to also fade them out..

Comment: I still don't see why you wouldn't know their duration here... `vidElement.duration` will give you just that. Then, you just have to compare `if(vidElement.duration - vidElement.currentTime <= 0.3) fadeOut()`, and indeed @str is correct that the `timeupdate` event is a good place to do this check.

Comment: I understand now that these are the media events I would need to use and I thank you and @str for pointing that out to me. The problem is that I have no idea how to actually use this. i would be really grateful if you could help me out by updating my JSFiddle. If you could post your solution as an answer I am sure it will also help others in the future.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9pv128tm/3 don't even try to make these fade effect yourself. But your question is not asking the correct question, so I won't post an answer (and I lack time to do it anyway :P)

Comment: That is an elegant solution and exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for your time and effort!